# How to run code inside a loop that's not code

Tags: python, string

I have created a loop that will generate the code I need, however, it is stored as a string and I am unsure how to make this string into executable code.

I have tried `eval()` and `exec()` however it throws up an error.

Here's what I have:

```
for connum in range(farOut):
checker = (f"check{connum} = result['ask'].iloc[{connum}]")
print(checker)
connum=connum+1
```

I get the desired output printed (which varies in the number count):

```
> check0 = result['ask'].iloc[0] 
> check1 = result['ask'].iloc[1]
> check2 = result['ask'].iloc[2]
```

However, what I need to do is then run this `check0, check1, check2... etc` as code.

So, I need to get the correct result for checker from the output of check0, check1, check2 and so on.

I know I'm fairly close, just need the missing pieces. I tried eval() but it throws up an error:

`eval(checker)`

```
File "<string>", line 1
    check0 = result['ask'].iloc[0]
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

`exec(checker)`
No error - just returns the output above:

```
> check0 = result['ask'].iloc[0] 
> check1 = result['ask'].iloc[1]
> check2 = result['ask'].iloc[2]
```

Comment: You have an IndentationError. Beside that: there should **never** be any reason to create strings of code to eval or exec them

Comment: `results = [result['ask'].iloc[whatever] for whatever in range(farOut)]` - result[0] == check0 etc.

Comment: Whenever you feel the urge to create a sequence of numbered variables, stop and use a list or dictionary!

Comment: Thanks for all the feedback. Created a new list now checkerlist = [] and that's going to help me work further through this. I appreciate best practices tips here.

Comment: Key value pairs? Is that not good for you?

Comment: @PatrickArtner thanks - this worked for me.
    results = [result['ask'].iloc[i] for i in range(farOut)]
    print(num, results)