# How to execute code inside a list using a for loop

Tags: python, list

I have a list, called checkerlist[] containing n items.

Here's how the values look (incrementally rises by 1):

```
check0 = result['ask'].iloc[0]
check1 = result['ask'].iloc[1]
```

and so on.

Essentially, I want to execute each line inside a for loop:

```
for ask in checkerlist:
           eval(ask)
```

However, I get this error:

```
  File "<string>", line 1
    check0 = result['ask'].iloc[0]
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

But if I were to run

```
check0 = result['ask'].iloc[0]
check0
```

I would get the desired result: 2.5

What am I doing wrong?

For reference- I hadn't originally had this code inside a list, just printed it out as is. However, adding it to a list has made it far more manageable (I'm still learning python). So any best practices you feel you can share will be well received.

Comment: of which structure are the "items"? How looks like check0?

Comment: How have you defined checkerlist ?

Comment: try without eval then...

Comment: @cruisepandey checkerlist = [] is defined at the start of the code (didn't add it to this question). So yes, it's there. Trying type(checkerlist) returns list

Comment: @cards without eval and using print(ask) returns the list position value as a string - check0 = result['ask'].iloc[0]

Comment: @Kevin ok, but could you give an example of the structure of such string? is a statement? an expression? I guess here the point

Comment: Isn't this a duplicate of [How to run code inside a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68790991/how-to-run-code-inside-a-loop-thats-not-code) where the consensus was this was a bad idea?  Meaning, it's better to store values in a list or dictionary than storing them in variable names i.e. check0, check1, etc.

Comment: I took that information on board and did store as a list. It was a big help. But I still had trouble executing the code which was answered by nikichiko

Comment: @Kevin--The comments from the other answers were to discourage generating a list with executable code since there are only a few special circumstances where this is needed.  The normal Python solution is to use Patrick Artner's suggestion of: `results = [result['ask'].iloc[i] for i in range(n)]` for n values.  Then `print(results)` which is faster and safer to run.  If the result is a Dataframe then even simpler: `result['ask'].tolist()` for list of values.

Comment: @DarrylG you're right - I just tried Patrick's code there and it works great. I have revisited that question and updated on his comment. Thanks for following up on this. I was able to get this working using a list, however, this method works great and does indeed seem faster for my needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for `exec`, and not `eval`. Eval will evaluate some string value and return the value, no `=` in there. With `exec` you can actually run code as a string.

Something like:

```py
for ask in checkerlist:
    exec(ask)
```

Comment: I had tried that and nothing displayed, so I added:
for ask in checkerlist:
           print(exec(ask))
and it returns
None

as the answer

Comment: Yes!! That is supposed to happen. Because you see, the assignment operation returns None. you can just as well do, `print(check0 = result['ask'].iloc[0])` and it will still give None.

Comment: If you want to print, you should add `print(checkN)` to each of the items in the checkerlist. So, each element should be something like `"check = result['ask'].iloc[0]; print(check0)"`. Then when you do `exec(ask)`, it will also print check0

Comment: Boom! That worked thank you! I learned a lot from this, thanks for your patience.